# Unity Custom Editor When I create 2D array toggle I and they are can not clickable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am leanring about custom editor and i have a problem is about SerializeObject, i create a 2D array 
toggles and i found they all not working when i click them.I try anything I can do, but it still not work
Can anyone help me?

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    serializedObject.Update();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUIStyle s1 = new GUIStyle();
        s1.padding.top = 20;
        s1.padding.left = 2;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Site " + (i+1).ToString(), s1, GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Site " + (i+1).ToString(), GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            SerializedProperty r = TheNewList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative("road").GetArrayElementAtIndex(j);
            SerializedProperty w = TheNewList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative("weight").GetArrayElementAtIndex(j);
            serializedObject.Update();
            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField((j+1).ToString(), GUILayout.MaxWidth(10));
            }
            r.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(m_Target.roadEditor[i].road[j]);
            if (setWeight)
            {
                w.intValue = (int)EditorGUILayout.IntField((int)m_Target.roadEditor[i].weight[j], GUILayout.MaxWidth(21));
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the additional

```
serializedObject.Update();
```

in the `for` loop!

This loads in the current values into the serialized properties in every iteration. This means even if you change a value which is not the very last toggle the current value gets reloaded before the Editor reaches the line

```
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

---

General note: Do **not** mix SerializedProperties and the direct access to your class fields via the `target`!

Best don't use the `target` at all ... there are some exceptions where you want to call a method or something but in general stick to only use `SerializedProperty`!

In your case you could simply do

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    // A little bonus see below
    DrawScriptField();

    // Note: you only want to begin a change check if you also end it somewhere
    // with the according if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) { ... } block
    //EditorGUI.BeginchangeCheck();

    // This you only want to do once for each OnInspectorGUI iteration
    serializedObject.Update();

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        // Get all these only ONCE instead of in every iteration of the inner loop
        var element = TheNewList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        var road = element.FindPropertyRelative("road");
        var weight = element.FindPropertyRelative("weight");

        // I like to wrap my code blocks in { } when possible in order to keep 
        // it a bit cleaner. Does only owrk ofcourse if you don't declare variables
        // you need later. On this way I don't forget to end the draw groups
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            var s1 = new GUIStyle { padding = { top = 20, left = 2 } };

            if (i == 0)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Site " + (i + 1), s1, GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Site " + (i + 1), GUILayout.MaxWidth(40));
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                var r = road.GetArrayElementAtIndex(j);
                var w = weight.GetArrayElementAtIndex(j);

                EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.LabelField((j + 1).ToString(), GUILayout.MaxWidth(10));
                    }

                    // By simply using PropertyField the Inspector automatically 
                    // - choses the correct drawer according to the property type
                    // - reads and writes the value to the serializedproperty and handles undo/redo etc
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(r, GUIContent.none, GUILayout.MaxWidth(10));

                    if (setWeight)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(w, GUIContent.none, GUILayout.MaxWidth(21));
                    }
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}

// This you get as a little bonus from my side ;)
private void DrawScriptField()
{
    EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
    EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((YOURSCRIPTTYPE)target), typeof(YOURSCRIPTTYPE), false);
    EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

    EditorGUILayout.Space();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try this later, I leave my pc at another city